# Nginx Ingress Controller not rewriting

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, nginx-ingress

I have this nginx ingress manifest file

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dados-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: "example.com.br"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /test(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: nodejs-teste2-svc
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: nodejs-teste-svc
            port:
              number: 80
```

There are two workloads running

`nodejs-teste-svc`

```bash
[GET] / -> Hello World
[GET] /version -> "{\"version\": \"1.0.0\"}"
```

and

`nodejs-teste2-svc`

```bash
[GET] / -> Hello World - Another version
[GET] /version -> "{\"version\": \"2.0.0\"}"
```

Based on the nginx file, I'd like that any request to `/test*` to be redirected to the right service, like this:

```bash
[GET] /test -> nodejs-teste2-svc.default.svc.cluster.local/

[GET] /test/version -> nodejs-teste2-svc.default.svc.cluster.local/version

[GET] / -> nodejs-teste-svc.default.svc.cluster.local/

[GET] /version -> nodejs-teste-svc.default.svc.cluster.local/version
```